# Why same theme doesn't apply to different views in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have created a **two view for displaying and editing using Razor in MVC.**

When I run the program the page background image appears and works as I want, but **when I click on the edit link it loads the edit view and it just shows a white background**.

The first time I thought it doesn't apply the theme. Then I **selected the edit view and run it again**. There I **could see the background image as I expected**. But when I go to the **displaying view, there wasn't any background image**.

Why is this happening? Any suggestions?
**These are two images relevant to displaying view and edit view**.

[image: Display view]

[image: Edit view]

This is the view of the page display page

```html
@model OnlineElection.DAL.person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <h4>Profile</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal" style="width:40%; margin-left:10%">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.password)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "" } })
        </dd>


    </dl>

</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.SID })
</p>
```

Code of edit view

```html
@model OnlineElection.DAL.person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Person_ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminApproved, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminApproved)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminApproved, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: @user449689, I have added the code. Please check

Comment: the background should come from the layout right? Isn't one of the css you are importing overriding the background?